Change fields in visual according to selected value of slicer in Power BI
I am new to Power BI and got stuck at creating a dashboard wherein we are required to change visuals according to selected value of slicer.
If revenue is selected than all the visuals should be in context of revenue and if profit is selected, all should be of profit.
I've done the required using buttons and bookmarks, however, while using field parameter I am not able to change the values of clustered bar chart.Select a value Visual should be according to the selected value
Since clustered column chart requires two values of y axis, I am not able to figure out what should I select other than the field parameter.
I created field parameter of profit and revenue. Normally for the y axis of visual, I select the newly created field parameter but here I have to select 2 values, one for revenue/profit this year and other for revenue/profit last year and I can't figure out the approach.
Please help. Thanks

Check usage of SWITCH in measures and hopefully it will solve your issue - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax

If you created a field parameter, then instead of the profit or revenue measures, you'd just drop the field parameter into your VALUES section.

@Pieter I thought of doing this but the problem is I have to add 2 values of Y Axis . So, if revenue is selected, I have to add this year revenue as well as last year revenue to y axis and the field parameter only has revenue(and profit)

you can try this:
Below is a simple sample data.
month   revenue profit
1   100 20
2   200 50
3   300 80
4   400 70
5   500 150
6   600 30
create a table2 only contains revenue and profit
option
revenue
profit
create a measure
MEASURE =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[option] ) = "revenue",
    SUM ( 'Table'[revenue] ),
    IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[option] ) = "profit", SUM ( 'Table'[profit] ) )
)




Thanks @Ryan
I actually wanted clustered column chart for both of them, so it revenue is selected, both the values, this year revenue and previous year revenue should be displayed same case for profit.
Thankfully I was able to solve the issue and have posted the solution that worked for me below.
Thanks for your input

Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78585148/apply-top-10-filter-according-to-selected-value-of-field-parameter-power-bi


Solved the issue by getting selected value of slicer using
selectedValue DAX function and created a common measure for this
year profit and this year revenue as well as last year profit and
last year revenue.
Changed their value according to selected value from slicer using
switch so that if user selects revenue, then [last year] should have
measure related to last year revenue else it should have measure
related to last year profit and similar process for [this year]
At the end used these two measures for values of my y-axis.
Thanks everyone for your help!

